# The users watch function in Google Admin Directory SDK, suddenly throws exception for wrong argument projection

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have a cloud function on GCP which runs for more than 18 months. Suddenly a week ago it stopped working.

**The code**

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
        
adminDirectoryService = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials = gsuiteCredentials, cache_discovery=False)

result = adminDirectoryService.users().watch(body=watchBody, projection=projection, event=eventType, maxResults=1, customer=gSuiteCutomerId, viewType=viewType).execute()
```

**The exception**:

```
result = adminDirectoryService.users().watch(body=watchBody, projection=projection, event=eventType, maxResults=1, customer=gSuiteCutomerId, viewType=viewType).execute()
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.7.8-py3.7.egg/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 723, in method
    raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "projection"
```

I have no idea what is causing the issue. I have checked the [documentation](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.html#watch) and it clearly states the `projection` argument exists.

Does anyone else encounter the issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following have fixed my issue:
I have removed the *projection*, *maxResults*, and *viewType* arguments from my request, and all worked fine.

Some explanation of why the issue happened. The googleapiclient.discovery builds the API based on JSON provided to it. Seems like Google changed the returned JSON without saying those braking changes to anyone.

The JSON can be found [here](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/admin/directory_v1/rest) (for *admin*, *directory_v1*)

If anyone is using a different version or API. I have found the source by looking at the discovery code [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/f76e403b697bee7e5f265123fe7bef3706d0d28e/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L90).

I hope it will help anyone else.

**EDIT**

It seems the issue was fixed by Google. The workaround solution in this answer is not needed anymore

Comment: I have also filed a bug report to Google, and it can be found here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167259201